# Compare ISO 8601 date strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I want to compare ISO 8601 dates in javascript as strings instead of making Date objects for each string and comparing objects.

```
var date_array = ['2012-10-01','2012-11-27','2012-12-23'];
console.log(date_array[0] < date_array[1])  // gives true
console.log(date_array[1] > date_array[2])  // gives false
```

My reason for doing this is I believe string comparisons should be faster than making objects for each date string and comparing objects.

These comparisons seem to work as expected in some browsers.  Can I expect this sort of <strike>alphabetical</strike> **lexicographic**  string comparison to work in all browsers?  Is this method of date comparison actually faster than using Date objects?

Comment: If the format is from big unit --> small unit, and all the strings have the same length for each field (fill in leading 0 if necessary), then there should be no problem.

Comment: Relevant links: [Here](http://jsperf.com/date-object-creation/2) shows the ops/sec of using the _Date_ constructor, [here](http://jsperf.com/operator-vs-localecompage/3) is string comparison and [here](http://jsperf.com/inequality-str-vs-int) int comparison.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles), The components of an ISO 8601 date are in lexicographical order, so you should be fine to do the above

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using that comparison operator will look at the strings values [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which means the *dictionary order*.

In ASCII, the decimal digits are sequentially stored smallest (`0`, `0x30`) to largest (`9`, `0x39`). If they're consistently in this format, largest value (year) to smallest (day) and always `0` padded to the largest possible value, then these comparisons will be fine.