# Remove duplicate records with same status and preserve only latest

Tags: javascript

I have below object.

```
const data = [
  {
    status: 1,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 1,
    date: '2020-11-01',
  },
  {
    status: 2,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 4,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 5,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  }
]
```

I need to filter out records with status 4 and 5.

Also, need to have only latest record for status 1.

So the result would be like below.

```
 const data = [
      {
        status: 1,
        date: '2020-12-01',
      },
      {
        status: 2,
        date: '2020-12-01',
      },
]
```

This is what I have tried.

```
data.filter(obj => [1, 2, 3].includes(obj.status))
    .filter(obj => obj.status === 1)
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
```

But here I am losing object with other status.

I could do by storing filtered result first and then sorting and picking up the latest record, and use something like below

`const result = filteredResult.push(latestRecordWithStatusOne)`

But, is it possible to achieve this using the same chaining?

Comment: Is it only `status: 1` that gets de-duplicated? What happens if there's multiple `status: 2` records?

Comment: Yes, only `status: 1` will be depulicated. There won't have multiple entries for other status.

Comment: this might be what you're looking for

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374112/filter-unique-values-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Do you have to use `filter` twice and then `sort`?

Comment: No, If that can be avoided that will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filtering for `status` being 1,2 or 3, you can then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object with the latest `date` for each `status` value. Since the other status values don't have multiple entries, it's safe to use this code for all of them. You can then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to create your desired output array:

```js
const data = [{
    status: 1,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 1,
    date: '2020-11-01',
  },
  {
    status: 2,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 4,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  },
  {
    status: 5,
    date: '2020-12-01',
  }
]

const out = Object.values(data
  .filter(obj => [1, 2, 3].includes(obj.status))
  .reduce((c, obj) => {
    c[obj.status] = c[obj.status] || obj;
    if (obj.date > c[obj.status].date)
      c[obj.status].date = obj.date
    return c;
  }, {})
);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: @Nick Will comparing them without  formatting as `Date` will work fine? I mean, here you are comparing just string, and still it's working fine. How?

Comment: @Magnetaar it works because the dates are in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` and so they can be compared directly as strings

Comment: @Magnetaar see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715561/compare-iso-8601-date-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
const data = [{    status: 1,    date: '2020-12-01',  },
  {    status: 1,    date: '2020-11-01',  },
  {    status: 2,    date: '2020-12-01',  },
  {    status: 4,    date: '2020-12-01',  },
  {    status: 5,    date: '2020-12-01',  }
]
console.log([...new Set(Object.values(data
  .filter(obj => [1, 2, 3].includes(obj.status))).map(item => item.status))])
```

Comment: status is independent of the index. They may not  have status as their index.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in one go with a `reduce` function. Ignore the 4/5 status and check for newest status 1 and replace if needed. Otherwise, add the value.

```js
const data = [{
        status: 1,
        date: '2020-12-01',
    },
    {
        status: 1,
        date: '2020-11-01',
    },
    {
        status: 2,
        date: '2020-12-01',
    },
    {
        status: 4,
        date: '2020-12-01',
    },
    {
        status: 5,
        date: '2020-12-01',
    }
]

const filtered = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
    if ([4, 5].includes(currentValue.status)) {
            // don't add value since it's a status 4/5
        return accumulator;
    } else if (currentValue.status === 1) {
        // currentValue status is 1 so check if there is already one in the result
        const index = accumulator.findIndex(obj => obj.status === 1)
        if (index === -1) { 
                // no other status 1 so add it
            return [...accumulator, currentValue]
        } else if (accumulator[index].date < currentValue.date) {
                // newer status 1 so replace it
            return [...accumulator.slice(0, index), currentValue, ...accumulator.slice(index + 1)]
        } else {
                // already the newest so just return the current accumulator
            return accumulator;
        }
    } else {
            // any other status can just be added
        return [...accumulator, currentValue];
    }
}, []);

console.log(filtered)
```